# Foreach loop outputting letter rather than value

Tags: php, arrays

I have got the query below and i am trying to loop through the result but the echo only returns the second letter of the array instead of the whole 2nd array.

```
$tsql = "SELECT UserId, Email FROM Membership";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
while ($row) {
    $body .= $row[0];
    foreach($row as $email)
    {
        echo $email[1]. "<BR>   ";
    }
}
;
```

Comment: `$email` is not an array.

Comment: Several issues. Why two loops? Why only one fetch? Why calling both columns in *$row* *$email*, when only one of them really is? Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: `$row[0]` = userid; `$row[1]` = email. No need for `foreach`. Here's why you are getting the second letter, https://eval.in/504105.

Answer (score 1):

your code has too many issues. you should use something like

```
$tsql = "SELECT UserId, Email FROM Membership";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_assoc($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

        echo $row [UserId]. "<BR>   ";
        echo $row [Email ]. "<BR>   ";

};
```

Comment: Extra semi colon in while pz chk

Comment: sorry my mistake.. Fixed.. :) Thanks

Comment: `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC` can be used with `sqlsrv_fetch_assoc`? `Userid` and `Email` as array keys should be quoted.

Comment: And I suggest  u to also explain the issue. Than yur answer will get more vote